# Dynamic Sql Filter using tables

Tags: sql-server, database, filter

Any ideas on how this should be done with T-SQL queries?

I have two tables, **Table A** contain records I want to return but filter through. **Table B** contains the list of filters and class categories. New records are added to Table A all the time. The goal is to  dynamically categorized records in **Table A** based on the filters listed in **Table B**.

Example:

**Table A**

```
Name
------------
John Doe 
Mary Lamb
Peter Pan
Tom Sawyer
Suzie Lamb
Nancy Lamb
Josh Reddin
```

**Table B**:

```
Filter    | Category
----------------------
John%Doe% | Team 1 
%Lamb%    | Team 2
Tom%      | Team 1
```

Desired output:

```
Name        | Category
John Doe    | Team 1
Tom Sawyer  | Team 1
Mary Lamb   | Team 2
Suzie Lamb  | Team 2 
Nancy Lamb  | Team 2 
Peter Pan   | 
Josh Reddin |
```

I thought about doing the following but not sure if that's the best solution:

1. `SELECT Filter, category from TableB` (Get list of filters)
2. Using SQL Loop through filters returned in (1.) and find matches in Table A using `LIKE`.

   Example:

   ```
    SELECT name, Category 
    FROM Table A, Table B 
    WHERE Table A.Name Like (CURRENT filter FROM B)
   ```
3. Insert/append record(s) returned in (2.) into TempTable
4. ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM TempTable (this returns Names and categories as shown in the desired output)

   UNION

   SELECT * 
   FROM Table A 
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN TempTable on NAME 
   WHERE Category in null
   ```

   (This returns rows with no categories found...Peter Pan and Josh Reddin)

Any ideas?

How about performance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use combination of `like` and `left join`

```
select a.Name,b.Category
from tableA a left join tableB b on a.name like b.Filter
```